# Writing a program which continuously asks the user for input

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program where the user tries to guess a randomly generated number; basically, a classic number-guessing game.

My program is running pretty well but I can't find out how to ask the user to play the game again if the guessed number is correct, and also how to keep asking the user for guesses if the guessed number is incorrect.

Can somebody help me accomplish this?

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `while` loop to keep asking the user for input, as so:

```
int guess, answer = rand()%10;
while(cin >> guess){ // keeps on asking the user for input
    if(guess > answer){cout << "Too high!" << endl;}
    else if(guess < answer){cout << "Too low!" << endl;}
    else{
        cout << "Good job!" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @luci A note about `while(cin >> guess)`. The exit condition is `cin` being placed in a failure state after failing to read an integer from the stream. This could be because someone has closed the stream, inserted an end of file character, or typed in something that cannot be converted into an integer. Once a stream has failed, the fail flags need to be `clear`ed and the offending input, if any, must be removed or processed as something other than an integer.

Comment: Side note: `rand` sucks. It's probably more than good enough for this, but in general prefer to use the [random number facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) available in modern C++. [See this link for details and alternatives](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).